# Is there a way to use streams to return value from doing operations on elements

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, sum, java-stream

I have a `Train` class, with a `List<TrainCar>` containing objects from a `TrainCar` class.
I have a function in `Train` called `getTotalWeight()`. Each `TrainCar` has a function called `getWeight()` which returns a value.
Can I use streams in some way to make the body of the `getTotalWeight()` function looking like this?

```
return cars.stream().//some function//;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`mapToDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) to get a stream of the weights and then [`sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sum--) them:

```java
return cars.stream().mapToDouble(TrainCar::getWeight).sum();
```

Comment: Same but with `mapToInt` in case `getWeight` returns an `int` and not a `double`.